# Custom dojo build at functions level

Tags: javascript, build, dojo

We are creating a javascript library from scratch and we need some utilities functions, just like what dojo provides, e.g. xhr wrapper, simple inheritances and array manipulation, etc. We don't want to write these functions ourselves from scratch, but we also don't want to just copy and paste code from dojo.

Dojo provides the custom build mechanism, but it works on the module level. For example, in the custom build, you can specify to only add the `lang` module in the dojo base. But we may only need the `dojo.hitch` function in the `lang` module, but not the `dojo.clone` function that also included in the `lang` module. We have a tight constraint on the size of the library file, so we need to remove any unused code.

What we are seeking is a way to extract certain functions from a module and build these functions into a single javascript file. For example, say we need `dojo.mixin`, `dojo.declare` and `dojo.hitch` functions, then these functions' declaration and their dependent inner functions should be built into a single file.

Any suggestions?

**Update from my test result**

Thanks Stephen Chung for your great suggestion on how to solve this problem.

So basically I created a custom dojo build with four modules : `dojo._base.xhr`, `dojo._base.json`, `dojo._base.declare` and `dojo._base.lang`. The built dojo.js file is 149kb, after using Google Closure compiler with advanced mode, the size has reduced to 24kb and the unused functions have been removed. If we want to keep some functions, just add another javascript file like below:

```
window['dojo'] = dojo;
window['dojo']['requireLocalization'] = dojo.requireLocalization;
window['dojo']['moduleUrl'] = dojo.moduleUrl;
```

and compile it with dojo.js.

Unfortunately the size is still a little bigger. We have a size limit of 40k in total. But this is still a very good solution for other cases.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need such a minimal build?  To run it on mobile devices?

Comment: Yes. We need to run on mobile devices and the size limit is 40kb in total, including the utility library and other javascript files.

Comment: 40KB gzipped?  You'll probably need dojox.mobile.  If you don't need dijit's, I squeezed Dojo Core down to 21KB gzipped in my app (which uses quite a lot of things). With dead code removal, you can go down much further (e.g. if you don't use publish/subscribe, XHR, fx, i18n, formatting, the loader etc.).  See my analysis: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.dojo.devel/13922

Comment: I have a full iPad web app squeezed down to 70KB gzipped.  It uses much of Dojo Core, dijit.Dialog/dijit._Templated, and dojox.mobile.  If you are careful only to use minimal features, skip dijit, and be tight with your user code, you can meet 40KB gzipped quite easily.

Comment: you have not gone **all the way** yet.  :-)  You have to compile the minimal Dojo library together with your own code, and then remove the "dojo" namespace itself.  This way everything got squeezed down to one-character variables.  Therefore, you can still squeeze it down much further.  Get my stuff at Github (https://github.com/schungx/Dojo-Closure-Advanced) and look through the document.  Be **very careful** with dojo.declare -- read through my docs to understand how to handle mangled property names with get/set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo Core is written in a very compact manner, with a lot of cross callings (i.e. one function calling other functions) in order to save download bytes and reduce code size.

Therefore, you need a minimal set of Dojo Core functions, together with the functions that it calls.

In other words, what you need is a build that includes Dojo Core, but then *removes* any dead-code that is never called.

I'd suggest that you don't go about creating a minimal-footprint library by writing it from scratch yourself.  What you need is to use the Closure Compiler's Advanced Mode to process your Dojo application.  It removes dead code, optimizes the entire app, and fully obfuscates it.

And yes, it is possible to use the Closure Compiler with Dojo in Advanced Mode -- Dojo is probably the only popular library that can do it.  Read it [here](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/file/n2636749/Using_the_Dojo_Toolkit_with_the_Closure_Compiler.pdf?by-user=t).

Some statistics: A Closure-compiled Dojo app is typically around 25-30% smaller than the equivalent Dojo app in a Shrinksafe build.  It depends on how many Dojo Core features you use -- typically you may reduce Dojo Core up to 40% of the original size (i.e. reduce code size by up to 60%) from dead code removal alone.  Further reductions are more difficult, as you may have to start removing features like the Dojo loader etc.

Comment: @Alex, ask Bill Keese (I think he is also IBMer) about using Dojo with Closure.

Answer (score 1):

Are you fixed on dojo? Google's closure library offers a very similar package management system to dojo, as well as all the necessary scripts and tools you need to compile the javascript down to a single "executable". The closure library compiler is arguably one of the most advanced javascript minifiers you will find so if tight, concise javascript is your goal, this tool could help tremendously.

Comment: Yes. We have to use dojo due to legal issue and company's strategy.

Comment: @Alex Cheng, figures, since you seem to be from IBM China.  :-)  Definitely look into using the Closure Compiler (in Advanced Mode, don't settle for the Simple Mode stuff) with Dojo.  It should do what you want.